# JDBC: SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: mysql, ssl, jdbc, ssl-certificate

I've been struggling with a MySQL SSL connection through JDBC.

I've already imported the CA cert in a custom JKS truststore and the client key and client cert as PKCS12 in a custom JKS keystore then passed them as parameters in the code below.

`jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname?useSSL=true&amp;requireSSL=true&amp;trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:///path/to/truststore_mysql.ks&amp;trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=mypass&amp;clientCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:///path/to/keystore_cert_mysql.ks&amp;clientCertificateKeyStorePassword=mypass`

but did't work because of:
`sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

enabling SSL debug I can see:

`%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
http-nio-8080-exec-4, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = certificate_unknown
http-nio-8080-exec-4, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-8080-exec-4, called closeSocket()`

The weird thing is that everything works passing the the keystore and truststore file as VM arguments.

`-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore_cert_mysql.ks
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=mypass
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore_mysql.ks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=mypass`

So the question is: Why using the JDBC connection URL parameters doesn't work?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.